# JS addeventlistener click to parent not child

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-chrome-extension, click

I have parent and child parent is box which expands/colaps and child butons witch also on click handles other processess how to make parent not active on click when child is cliked?

this is parent:

```
$('#'+groupId)[0].addEventListener("click", collapseExpand);


<div id="title_group0">smth (1)<img id="coltitle_group0" src="chrome-extension://.../images/collapse.png" collapsed="yes" title="Show Divvies in this box" class="boxButton"><img src="chrome-extension://.../images/wrench_icon&amp;16.png" id="boxSettingsButton0" title="Settings" class="boxButton"><img style="display:none;" src="chrome-extension://.../images/sort_a.png" id="sorting_desc_asctitle_group0" class="sortIcon"><b style="display:none;" class="sortType">ABC</b></div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear..

Comment: Can you please post some HTML?

Comment: prevent the propagation of the click event from the child nodes

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` within the event listener of the child?

Comment: He is asking if we can prevent propagate DOWN the chain, from the parent to the child.   The question does not already have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [stop propagation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-Event-stopPropagation) (cancel bubbling) of the click:

```
$('#'+groupId)[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    collapseExpand(e); // You can omit the `e` if the function doesn't need it
});
```

By doing this within the child's event handler, you prevent the parent element from seeing the click.

---

Side note: You appear to be half-using jQuery. To fully use it:

```
$('#'+groupId).on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    collapseExpand(e); // You can omit the `e` if the function doesn't need it
});
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking to stop propagation to a CHILD of a parent.  Is this even possible? I am trying to do so in the example of a Modal window in which I want the user to be able to click outside the content of the modal.  ie: <div class="modal"> click outside <div class="content">STUFF</div> click outside </div>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use `event.stopPropagation()` like that :

```
$('#'+groupId).click(function(event){
    collapseExpand()
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

That will stop propagation of the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target !== this) return;

    alert( 'clicked the foobar' );
});
```

Try this-

http://jsfiddle.net/eaVzx/165/